# Unable to read pointer file: GIT LFS on docker

Tags: git, docker, git-lfs

I have an Ubuntu docker instance on which I am trying to clone a repo.

I am cloning it as follows:(before cloning, I did git lfs install)

```
git clone --recurse-submodules <Repo URL>
```

I get the following error:

```
Encountered 7 file(s) that should have been pointers, but weren't:
```

See this error for a zip file.

I did a quick search and then uninstalled and installed git lfs followed by git lfs pull, but did not help. I understand it means it is looking for a file in LFS format (basically something like a pointer).

I have done the same thing on a Ubuntu machine itself (non-docker) and it works. However, when I do the same thing on a docker instance on that same machine, I get this error.

Any inputs/suggestions on what the issue is.

Thanks in advance!